# Write a function that accepts an array of test scores as an argument then the function should return a number of scores that 80 or higher?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm still pretty new into JS but I'm having a hard time with this problem. I'm sure the answer is somewhat simple but i can't figure out what to put into the function expression after i've made my array of scores? Do i need to do a for loop?
Thanks

```
array = [20,30,40,50,60,70,80,92,93,95,98,100]

 function testScores(array){

 }
```

Comment: See generally: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: please add the result as well. do you need all values above or just a single value, the first or the smallest, or what ever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use array's filter method. please follow below definition.

```
function testScores(array){
 return array.filter(ele=>ele>=80)
}
```

Comment: He/She wants the number as output.

Comment: btw, `testScores` is plural.

Answer (score 0):

```
function testScores(array){
  return array.filter(number => number >= 80);
}
```

This will return an array of scores more 80 and above. 
e.g

```
let scores = [20,30,40,50,60,70,80,92,93,95,98,100];
testScores(scores)
```

If you just want the count of scores more than 80 you can do

```
testScores(scores).length
```

Comment: He/She wants the number as output.

Comment: btw, `testScores` is plural.